# Terraform ERROR: Inappropriate value for attribute "requires_compatibilities": set of string required

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-fargate

i get the following error message after terraform validate:

###############################################################

Error: Incorrect attribute value type
on .terraform/modules/backend_deployment/task_definition.tf line 4, in resource "aws_ecs_task_definition":

requires_compatibilities = "FARGATE"

Inappropriate value for attribute "requires_compatibilities": set of string required.

###############################################################

This is my task_definition:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_definition" {
  family = join("-", [local.cluster_values.backend_name, local.cluster_values.environment, local.cluster_values.random_id])
  network_mode = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = "FARGATE"
  cpu = 256
  memory = 512
  container_definitions = data.template_file.task_definition_template.rendered
  task_role_arn = local.cluster_values.task_role
}
```

Terraform-Doku says this:

requires_compatibilities - (Optional) Set of launch types required by the task. The valid values are EC2 and FARGATE.

Many thanks for helping !

Comment: Downvote for simply ignoring the error message *"**Set** of launch types required by the task"*.

Comment: Ah, yes "set of string required." is the error message, matches the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the error message, the provider is expecting an argument value of type `set(string)`, and you have provided `string`. You can fix this by providing a value consistent with the type expected by the provider according to the error message:

```
requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did not work for me

```
    // Apply the firewall rule to allow external IPs to access this instance
    tags = element(var.instance_tag, count.index)
}

variable "instance_tag" {
  type = list
  default = ["http-one", "http-two"]
}
```

Worked when added []

```
    // Apply the firewall rule to allow external IPs to access this instance
    tags = [element(var.instance_tag, count.index)]
}

variable "instance_tag" {
  type = list
  default = ["http-one", "http-two"]
}
```

There is another way to make it work as well with `type = list(string)`

```
    // Apply the firewall rule to allow external IPs to access this instance
    tags = element(var.instance_tag, count.index)
}

variable "instance_tag" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["http-one", "http-two"]
}
```